# How to find and count directory and files found in 'find'

Tags: bash, environment-variables, find

How to find and count directory and files found in find util in Bash Linux, and put in env. variable, or print out, or both, each e.g

```
NUM_FILE=
NUM_DIR=
```

of : (just illustration)

```
find . -type d ...... -o type f .......... -print..... # ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your directory/filenames don't contain newlines, piping the output of the `find` command into `wc -l` gives you the total number.

Using the usual command substitution, `var=$(....)`, puts the figure into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to count a file with newlines only once, print a dot for every file:

```
NUM_FILE=$(find . -type f -printf "." | wc -c)
NUM_DIR=$(find . -type d -printf "." | wc -c)
```